# Deciding higher priority order between a triple bond and tertiary carbon

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I want to know which of the groups will be given higher priority $\ce{-C#CH}$ or $\ce{-C(CH3)3}$ and why. I tried resolving the triple bond to single bonds such that they are phantom atoms. But that gave me a structure in which there are no atoms after the first point of difference. How is this (see image) wrong and if this is correct then isn't it a contradiction? After first point of difference, there are two difference one is nothing v/s $\ce H$ and other is $\ce C$ vs $\ce H$ and both situation seem to contradict in giving their respective group higher priority order.

[image]

Comment: I'll point out that there are different schemes for naming compounds. So the answer probably depends on exactly which one that you are using...

Comment: @marxw for E and Z or R and S we need to first give them priority  order. And i want to know which priority is correct and why.

Comment: At 2nd point of difference, the phantom carbon is attached to the original carbon and hence its a C-C v/s C-H and its obvious that the former will be given higher priority. Its not right to say that the phantom C is not linked to any atom if its really linked to the original C

Comment: For a similar question, [see this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/168666/what-determines-the-higher-priority-in-cip-rules-if-both-groups-have-the-same-a/168725#168725).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Ingold%E2%80%93Prelog_priority_rules#Double_and_triple_bonds) article on CIP rules.

> If an atom A is double-bonded to an atom B, A is treated as being singly bonded to two atoms: B and a "ghost atom" that is a duplicate of B (has the same atomic number) but is not attached to anything except A.

Ghost atoms are attached to resolve the triple/double bond.

So according to CIP rules the two compounds can be resolved as
[image]
 <sub>The pink atoms are ghost carbons</sub>

From here we can see that ethyne has a greater preference over isobutyl as after the first point of difference we move over to the next highest order carbon. In ethyne the second carbon is connected to $\ce{C2H}$ whereas the next highest order carbon in isobutyl is connected to $\ce{H3}$.

Comment: What about ethyne vs -C(CH₃)₂-C(CH₃)₂H ?  Does the latter win because they are connected to three hydrogens each, whereas the ghost carbon are not connected to anything?  But then what about... I will draw...