# Why are carbon atoms of glucose considered chiral?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

A chiral carbon atom is defined as

> "a carbon atom with four  different groups attached to it."

I am aware that the open-chain form of glucose has four chiral carbon atoms.

However, I do not undertstand why that is, since the alleged chiral atoms do not have **four** ***different*** substituents: For example, the 3rd carbon atom is bound to one hydrogen atom, one hydroxylgroup and **two** neighbouring carbon atoms.

[image]

Comment: 2 same atoms does not mean 2 same atomic groups.

Comment: Okay, but why is the last carbon atom at the bottom NOT considered chiral then?

Comment: Exception: 2 same atoms means 2 same groups if  the atom is the whole group.

Comment: Groups R-COOH and R-CH2OH are not the same, even if both are attached to R via C atom. Or, do you think they are the same?

Comment: @Johanna Similar to an onion, starting from the central atom to check if it is a chiral one / a stereogenic centre (and if so, on can assign *R*, or *S* configuration), one works toward more remote "shells".  User `@user55119` compiled instructive answers; just two of them [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/168666/what-determines-the-higher-priority-in-cip-rules-if-both-groups-have-the-same-a/168725#168725), and [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158052/why-is-the-chirality-center-in-1r-2s-2-fluorocyclopentane-1-carboxylic-acid-1/158058#158058).